# What's the meaning of "fumbling over the words"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

The [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fumble_1) says: Fumble means to try to hold, move, or find something using your hands in a way that is not skilful or graceful

Then, it explains the idioms Fumble for/about/with/around.

What does "Fumble Over" mean? And what's the meaning of "fumbling over the words" in Lie a little better song by Lucy Hale?

Comment: Why did you leave out the most relevant definition from your question? **fumble** (*verb*) to say something in a way that is not skillful or effective

Comment: Oh I'm sorry maybe I didn't see it. I did not know it's the most relevant definition because today I saw this verb for the first time and idk it's meaning at all. @J.R.

Comment: C'mon people why is there no answer till now? You don't need to write a long answer. Few hints are enough and I'll understand. Thanks you,

Comment: I'm not sure why the comment I've provided doesn't answer your question. Perhaps you should explain why, even after knowing that _fumble_ means "to say something in a non-skillful way," you still can't understand _fumbling over the words_. Oh, one other thing: please don't encourage people to answer in a cursory way. If you want this question to get more attention, try a [bounty](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Comment: @J.R. I knew the meaning of fumble but I did not know the meaning of "fumble over". I thought it's like "get in" where the preposition completely changes the meaning. Now, I know that adding "over" is like adding "to" to the verb "Go" where there's no significant change in the meaning. Sorry about the other things that I did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I will attempt to form some kind of answer that makes sense, perhaps it helps :)

So basically to **fumble** in this specific case could and should mean to stumble over or to trip over something.

Therefore, **"Fumbling over the words"** could simply imply to not be able to find the right words to say *(or write)*.

It could mean that someone is struggling to pick and choose the correct words to say *(or write)*, or perhaps that there is an abundant amount of words to choose from, but the person is uncertain which ones to choose. Technically, they are **fumbling** over them.

Here's a random usage of the word **fumbling** with this same context:

**"He was fumbling about in the dark like a headless chicken."**

*Sources*: [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fumbling)

Comment: I like your explanation, but I don't understand how your _headless chicken_ sentence could be labeled as "with this same context."

Comment: now that i look at it, you have a point, the context isn't the same in that one, rather the usage of the word is what i should have said. my apologies :D